# Save HTML5 SessionStorage After Close Browser

Tags: html, session, session-storage

How do I save the HTML5 session Storage after I close the browser?  Is this possible or not?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't be using localStorage instead? Are cookies not an acceptable solution? Please flick across a little more detail about what you're trying to achieve.
Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether you have looked at `localStorage` or not? If yes, you should be using that since the API is similar to that of `sessionStorage` and your data is persisted across browser restart but ofcourse limited to the particular domain namespace.

`sessionStorage` can be retrieved back if you close the browser. In fact, `sessionStorage` is unique to a particular window or tab only, so it is not just about the browser being closed but also about have two different `sessionStorage` properties.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by @Romin, `sessionStorage` is persistent only till the tab is open. [Refer to this](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/)

You should look at browser `localStorage`. Using something like [amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/) will greatly help you code cross-browser applications.